# sp_columns typename/data_type vs table designer: ntext vs nvarchar(MAX)

Tags: sql-server

In the Management Studio table designer, my table is `nvarchar(MAX)`, but in `sp_columns`, it says **TYPE_NAME** = `ntext` and **DATA_TYPE** = `-10`.

Which is correct? (I want to avoid `ntext` for future compatibility)

Comment: I think that is the same as `nvarchar`, same for `text` to `varchar`

Comment: ntext is going to be deprecated in future versions.... so they say, even through 2016 reportedly supports them.

Comment: So it's definitely nvarchar? Since ntext is being deprecated, I don't want to be using it in a new database.

Comment: @scsimon - yep, I'm aware of that, which is why I'm actually asking. :) I want to be 100% sure I'm using nvarchar and not ntext. Do I trust sp_columns or Management Studio?

Comment: I understand. What version of sql server are you on? This is interesting.

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate this on SQL Serer 2016. I created a table with ntext and nvarchar(max). Table designer reflected this as well, and it looks right in sys.columns.  `select 
 c.name
 ,c.system_type_id
 ,ty.name
 ,ty.precision
 ,t.name
from sys.columns c
inner join sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id
inner join sys.types ty on ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
where
t.name = 'deleteTable'
`

Comment: I'm using 2014. Although I've just checked 2016 and it has the same behaviour.

Comment: I think it might be related to database version, what is database version that you run the sp on?

Comment: @scsimon the designer and sys.columns are correct. It is the procedure sp_columns that does some funky stuff. See my answer below.

Comment: @SeanLange i couldn't figure out why so i hit up [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185976/why-does-sp-columns-sys-spt-columns-odbc-view-return-incorrect-results) as well. But like you, couldn't narrow down what that system view is doing

Comment: @scsimon I avoid the system views as they are not always accurate and don't have all the data that I often want to see. But this one is an extended procedure so you can easily view the code...but be warned...those procedures make you scratch your head as to why they were implemented the way they are. Of course many of them have been around for a LONG LONG time now and never get updated.

Comment: i felt the same way looking at the comments of that proc @SeanLange

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/186028/95107

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sp_columns procedure returns some strange information sometimes. I prefer to look directly at the column in sys.columns which is where the column definition is defined.

It is easy to replicate your example and demonstrate that is in fact nvarchar(max).

```
create table TextTest
(
    VarCharCol nvarchar(max)
    , NTextCol ntext
)

go

exec sp_columns 'TextTest'

select ColumnName = c.name
    , ColumnDataType = t.name 
from sys.columns c
join sys.systypes t on t.xusertype = c.user_type_id
where object_id = OBJECT_ID('TextTest')
```